# computing the second derivative of $F(t)=f(a+t(x-a))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $F(t)=f(a+t(x-a))$, where $x\not = a$ and $x,a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I need computing $F''(t)$.

Well by chain rule, $F'(t)=(x-a) \cdot \nabla f(a+t(x-a))$ but what is $F''(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a curve $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$
\varphi(t) := a + t(x-a).
$$
You already showed that
$$
F'(t) = Df(\varphi(t))\cdot \varphi'(t).
$$
$\varphi'(t)$ is constant and can thus be ignored when differentiating. Just apply the chain rule again:
$$
F''(t) = (D^2 f(\varphi(t) \cdot \varphi'(t))) \cdot \varphi'(t) = (x-a)^\top D^2(a+t(x-a)) (x-a)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{a}+t(\mathbf{x-a})$.
The differential writes
$d\mathbf{y}=(\mathbf{x-a}) dt$

Then
$F'(t)=\mathbf{g}^T(\mathbf{x-a})$ where
$\mathbf{g}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{y}}$.

From
$d\mathbf{g}
=\mathbf{H}_f d\mathbf{y}
=\mathbf{H}_f (\mathbf{x-a}) dt$
it holds
$F''(t)
=(\mathbf{x-a})^T \mathbf{H}_f (\mathbf{x-a})$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are in Euclidean coordinates so $x=(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ so that $\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)_{i=1}^n$. Then
$$\frac{d}{dt} (\nabla f) ( a + t(x-a)) = \left( \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a + t(x-a))\right)_{i=1}^n= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial  x_i\partial x_j}(x-a)_j\right)_{i=1}^n=H(f) (x-a) $$ where $H(f) = \left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial  x_i\partial x_j}\right)_{i,j=1}^n$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$. Therefore we have

$$F''(t) = (x-a)\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\nabla f(a+t(x-a)) =(x-a)^T \frac{d}{dt}\nabla f(a+t(x-a)) = (x-a)^T H(f) (x-a) $$

So $$F''(t) = (x-a)^T H(f) (x-a)$$

Answer (score -1):

$F$ is $f$ along the slice given by $a+t(x-a)$. As such the dericative to $F$ in $t_0$ is the derivative to $f$ in the point $a+t_0(x-a)$ and the direction $(x-a)$, which is an interpretation of your chain rule thing. Similarly the second derivative to $F'$ will be the second derivative of $f$ in $a+t_0(x-a)$ twice in the direction of $(x-a)$. If $f$ has a second total derivative $D_2$ (that is a bilinear map that maps $v,w$ to the second order derivative of $f$ in directions $v,w$) we can write this as $D_2(x-a)(x-a)$.

Similar to $D_1$ being given by $\nabla f$ we can also under the assumption that our functions are nice take $D_2$ to be the hessian $\mathrm Hf$ to $f$.

Comment: What is your explicit answer about $F''(t)$?

Comment: @TheMartian Well, as long $f$ is nice enough it is $\mathrm H_f(a+t_0(x-a))(x-a)(x-a)$.

Comment: @TheMartian Which is the quadratic form of $\mathrm H_f(a+t_0(x-a))$ in $(x-a)$.

Comment: @TheMartian What I don’t get is why anyone would vote this down and all later answers up, when my answer just states the same, just more generalised. I just do not understand the dynamics of this site, sometimes people are getting tons of upvotes for total shit answers that do not in fact answer the point behind the whole thing, just because the answer sounds good. I think I’ll just quit SE at some point, it’s just so frustrating!